# How to fetch nested dictionaries in JSON?

Tags: python, json, django

I'm having some trouble understanding why I am not able to fetch some datas in my JSON datas. I'm on Django using JSONField, I'd like to change some specific datas after fetching them. Here's what I wrote:

```
for apple in Apples.objects.filter(json__contains=[{'provenance': 'Spain'}]):
    for ap in apple.json:
        for key, value in ap.items():
            print(value.color)
```

> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'color'

when I print `value` I have something like this:

```
{'color': 'red', 'size': '20x20', 'good_till': '01.08.2017'}
```

So I don't understand why the error says that there's no attribute `color` while there's one? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `value['color']` instead of `value.color`?

Comment: @Christoph Yes this is it, I don't understand why I couldn't find this information on other posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need:

```
print (value.get('color', ''))
```

because color is the key, but not the attribute

Comment: I know it is possible to assign `value['color'] = 'yellow'` a new color but is it there a way to do so with `value.get('color', '') = "green"` ?

Answer (score 1):

Hey so using the dot notation such as "print(value.color)" is how would do it on the html side of things using jinja, however when in a python file to access a value of a key it uses square brackets. Hope this helps

value['color'] would return red.
so to change it 
value['color'] = blue will change it 
and then in html do {{ value.color }}.
Hope this helps